# PHPUnit and Yii on a shared server

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

I have installed `PHPUnit` and checked my `PEAR` settings and everything went fine. I'm using `Yii` as my framework and I am on a linux shared server.  When I run a test (any test) I get the errors below.  From what I can tell I think I need to add the following to my path settings:

```
/home/myname/php/
```

since that is where both the PHP and `PHPUnit` folders are located.  I am unable to modify the php.ini file since I am on a shared server.  I am wondering if this is really the problem and if anyone else has found and fixed this issue in a shared environment?

```
/protected/tests/unit]# phpunit dbTest.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myname/bin/phpunit on line 40<br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/myname/bin/phpunit on line 40
```

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and tribulation I figured it out.  Hope this helps someone else.

Since I am on a shared server I cannot adjust the include_path.  It won't work using a .htaccess file either because phpunit is run from the command line and doesn't invoke the .htaccess file.  Therefore, setting an include path in a .htaccess is fruitless if you're having the same problems as I was with phpunit.

The only path that I am now able to get phpunit tests to run from is /home/myname/php.  That is because my PHPUnit files automatically install in /home/myname/php/PHPUnit.

When running a phpunit test from /home/myname/php I would get an error stating

`File &quot;/home/... &quot; could not be found`

At this point I found that I needed to upgrade PHPUnit, which in turn upgraded a number of its dependencies (CodeCoverage, Selenium and others).  The command to upgrade phpunit was

```
pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Now I can successfully run tests from the /home/myname/php folder and it works.  If I run the tests from any other folder it fails because it is searching the include_path directories and /home/myname/php is not one of those paths.

Answer (score 0):

check that your PHPUnit exists in /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit, ortherwise, you have to include your path for your PHPUnit in your PHP.ini.

check your Loaded Configuration File (PHP.ini) you are using with

`php --ini`

put a PEAR directory in "include_path" line.

Comment: Because I am on a shared server, PHPUnit exists in /home/myname/php/PHPUnit.  I do not have access to write to /usr/lib/php and PHPUnit does not exist there.  PEAR is installed correctly and is in the php.ini file.  It's there by default.  I do not have access to change the server's php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, try to add /home/myname/php/ to your path like:

```
export PATH=/home/myname/php/:$PATH
```

Also, look at http://php.net/set_include_path