# Setting up Yii on Shared Server

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I wish to use a PHP Framework such as Yii, however, it seems to set this up I need access to a terminal or console. Unfortunately my only access to the server is via an FTP client as it's shared hosting.

Does this rule Yii out as a framework?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171528/phpunit-and-yii-on-a-shared-server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7714-shared-hosting-no-ssh/) you can generated all files on your computer and then just upload the files to your shared hosting.

Answer (score 12):

all you need to do is

1 - have a copy of yii framework folder

2 - generate a new yiic webapp folder

3 - upload both folders, the framework folder can go to some hidden place yoursite.com/wawa/framework/yii, and you can just upload the files in your webapp folder to yoursite.com/

4 - edit the index.php in your generated web app, so it know where your framework/yii folder is. than you are set

5 - just make different copy of your webapp folder, so you don't need to generate them if you dont want to. just use different names, wont make a difference, as long as the webapp index.php knows where your framework folder is, than it will work

Comment: This question has already had an answer accepted 6 months ago. Appreciate the effort, but your a little too late!

Comment: Just thinking that this is more to the point and easy to follow for the beginners

Comment: @devric - you got my +1.  Thanks, it was helpful - you're never too late :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need a terminal for developing on your local server (it isn't a good idea to develop directly on a shared server). To use it on a shared server just upload it.

In the strict sense you don't need a terminal. You could write your files yourself. The `yiic` program only creates a couple of php files.

Comment: all the required files for the framework are generated upon running the yiic file from the terminal, it's like step 1 of the installation. How would I access the web area if I just upload it?

Comment: The issue is that I'm new to it, I've never used it before so I would NEED the skeleton application it generates

Comment: You need a local development server (on your machine) to develop the website. There you can use the terminal for generating the application skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

I am first in Yii. Installed the application locally. FTP-ing the application to the share server in directory /home/sloki/user/h11741/sites/example.com/www then create abcd directory within /www and put framework into it.

Edit your index.php line 4 to be: $yii=dirname(**FILE**).'/abcd/framework/yii.php';

You will get error message like this

*Application runtime path "/home/sloki/user/h11741/sites/example.com/www/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.*

Change permission of directories /protected/runtime and /assets to 777. Test the web, when success change again permission both directories to 775.

Gut lak.